# How can i output specific rows using a select form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a select option form and i would like to get the selected data from my database.

The table looks like this:

```
id | brand | types | size
1 | nike | tshirt | L
2 | nike | shorts | XL
3 | puma | cap | foo
4 | jordans | shoes | foo
```

This is what i've tried:

```
<?php
    include_once '../dbc.php';

    $brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['brand']);
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['type']);
    $size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['size']);
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['price']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brand='$brand'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($resultCheck > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['type'].'">'.$row['type'].'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
```

The result should look like this, when selecting `nike` it should add the options `tshirt` and `shorts` from the database into the `<select name="type">`

```
<form id="clothesList">
<select name="brand">
    <option value="nike">nike</option>
    <option value="puma">puma</option>
    <option value="jordan">jordans</option>
</select>
<select name="type">
    <!-- Show here all avilable options from database -->
    <option value="tshirt">tshirt</option>
    <option value="shorts">shorts</option>
</select>
<select name="size">
    <!-- After selecting brand, type it should show the sizes -->
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I also figured out how to get the values when changed:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#clothesList select').change(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Comment: You appear to be asking (at least) two different questions; how to build the markup, and something about something with the script.  Please narrow the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to make calls, let's say you pick nike, use ajax to grab options under nike, and append each option to select. and when you pick tshirts, do the same thing, until there are no more options left.

Comment: But how do i make the SQL call? I have `WHERE brand='$brand'` but how do i specify that i want only the "types" where the brand is nike ?

Comment: Can you start with change type to types echo '<option value="'.$row['types'].'">'.$row['types'].'</option>'; also, instead of use while loop, try foreach loop